# Flex/AIR Mobile: TabbedViewNavigator selectedIndex not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.6

I have a Mobile Project in FB 4.6 with a TabbedViewNavigator. I have 4 buttons at the bottom, which are ViewNavigators, and act as the Tabs. For this instance, lets say the tabs are labeled, HOME, ADD, DELETE, and ABOUT. I am running into the following situation:

1. User presses the ADD tab.
2. In the ADD screen, user clicks on several links which takes them away from the ADD tab's firstView and to a new view all together. For this instance, let's say the active view is called PlayersView.
3. User now clicks another tab, for example HOME.
4. User decides to go back to the ADD tab. However, upon pressing the ADD tab, the user is taken to the last view, which in this case was the PlayersView.

How can I have the functionality changed so that upon pressing a Tab, the user is ALWAYS taken to the firstView property of that tab. As referenced above, this is not happening. I have tried creating an IndexChangeEvent listener on the tabbedNavigator and then changing the tabbedNavigator's selectedIndex, however this doesn't work.

```
protected function tabbedviewnavigatorapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {

      this.tabbedNavigator.addEventListener(IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE,onIndexChange);
}


protected function onIndexChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {

      this.tabbedNavigator.selectedIndex = event.newIndex;
      trace(' THIS DOESN'T WORK');
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, when you set

```
tabbedNavigator.selectedIndex
```

you switch between different ViewNavigators, not between different Views inside a `ViewNavigator`.

As I understand it, you are trying to stay *within* a single `ViewNavigator` stack and select the first `View`.

Let's say you have:

```
<s:navigators>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="addSomethingNavigator" firstView="views.AddView"/>
    <s:ViewNavigator id="deleteSomethingNavigator" firstView="views.DeleteView"/>
</s:navigators>
```

You can pop to a specific ViewNavigator's first `View` like so:

```
addSomethingNavigator.popToFirstView();
```

Comment: Thanks. After I asked the question I realized that I was, in fact, asking two different questions. However, the primary question was how to jump back to the first view, which you did indeed answer. Thank you for the assistance.